# Error while conditional rendering of state value using ternary operator inside jsx in Reactjs 18.0

Tags: reactjs, use-state, conditional-operator

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [points, setPoints] = useState({ playerOne: 0, playerTwo: 0 });
  const [state, setState] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h3> value is {points.playerOne} & {points.playerTwo} </h3>
      <h3> points of player one is {state === true ? 1 : 2} </h3>
      <h3> points of player one is {state === true ? {points.playerOne} : {points.playerTwo}} </h3>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I can't understand why I am facing an error due to the third **h3** tag

```
<h3> points of player one is {state === true ? {points.playerOne} : {points.playerTwo}} </h3>
```

if I comment this above line of code then output is rendering fine

Use the link to run the code --  https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-grass-wdoq68?file=/src/App.js

please help!

Comment: You have extra curly brackets. It should be `{state === true ? points.playerOne : points.playerTwo}`

Comment: Typo.  You have unnecessary `{}` characters.  The "working" line of code *just above that* doesn't use them, this line of code shouldn't either.  In JSX curly braces denote a block of code (containing an expression), but in this case you're *already in* that expression.

Comment: thnx Nicolas and David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the curly braces in `Conditional (ternary) operator` Do this:

```
  <h3> points of player one is {state  ? points.playerOne : points.playerTwo} </h3>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-voice-crbtjp

Comment: thnx man it is working. I used the curly braces inside first h3 tag also.  therefore i used in the ternary operator also